How do I change the color of the multiple y-axis in a plotly parcoords plot?
I can use the layout in order to change the color of x-axis and y-axis in scatterplots in plotly, however I am not able to change the color of the multiple y-axes that exist in a parcoords plot. Here is what I have achieved so far:
library(plotly)
textColor <- "red"
lineColor <- "orange"
plot_ly(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100)) |>
  plotly::layout(
    xaxis = list(tickfont = list(color = textColor), color = lineColor),
    yaxis = list(tickfont = list(color = textColor), color = lineColor)
  )

plot_ly(
  type = "parcoords",
  dimensions = list(
    list(
      label = "a",
      values = runif(100)
    ),
    list(
      label = "b",
      values = runif(100)
    ),
    list(
      values = runif(100),
      label = "c"
    )
  )
) |> plotly::layout(
  font = list(color = textColor),
  yaxis = list(tickfont = list(color = textColor), color = lineColor)
)




You can see that the three y-axes are still black and not orange.
What would a working solution? A python solution would be enough for me.

I couldn't find a corresponding option in the Plotly library for R, but you could take the ggplot-route via {GGally} as shown here.
In your case:
library(GGally)

create sample dataframe (required for ggplot & Co):

    d <- Map(1:3, f = \(i) runif(99)) |> 
      setNames(letters[1:3]) |>
      list2DF()
    
    d$dimension <- gl(3, 33, labels = letters[1:3])


create plot and convert to Plotly:
p <- ggparcoord(d,
           columns = 1:3,
           groupColumn = 'dimension'
           ) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour = 'orange'))

Here, the vertical grid color is set through the theme. For individually styled vertical lines see ?ggplot2::geom_vline.


Unfortunately this way you lose most of the interactivity (like marking parts of y-axis, reordering y-axis etc) so this is not an option. But thanks for the idea!

Noskario, you're right. I'm only afraid the library for R doesn't offer this (nor does the one for Python from what found in a semi-ambitious research). If it doesn't have to be Plotly, e4charts might be worth a try.
